# How do I allow edit only a particular column in datagridview in windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to enable only two columns in the DataGridview to be able to edit.
The others should not be allowed to edit.
Further I am not directly linking to datasource;
I will be doing some thing like this way

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Email");
dt.Columns.Add("email1");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Email"] = i.ToString();
    dr["email1"] = i.ToString() + "sdf";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

So which property should I set, that will enable only one column say Email(in the above eg) to be editable.

Comment: What platform? WinForms?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Set the `ReadOnly` property of the other columns to `true`.

(You'll probably need to loop through the `Columns` collection and use an `if` statement)

Answer (score 32):

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
```

here first column (index 0) will be editable.

Answer (score 24):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridViewX1.Columns)
{
       if (dc.Index.Equals(0) || dc.Index.Equals(1))
       {
           dc.ReadOnly = false;
       }
       else
       {
            dc.ReadOnly = true;
       }
 }
```