# Fail to make only one column editable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I cannot make single column to be editable in `DataGridView`. I tried to do it in the designer but didn't get positive results. I tried scripting it like

```
datagridview1.Columns["theColumn"].ReadOnly=false;
```

but that didn't work. Seems like the property of ReadOnly in `DataGridView` is only that is considering, no other modifications count. I actually try to make `DataGridViewColumn` that contains CheckBoxes editable, while other columns I get from DataBase.

Comment: See if this link helps you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597268/how-do-i-allow-edit-only-a-particular-column-in-datagridview-in-windows-applicat

Comment: That way you listed should work just fine, are you maybe misspelling the column index?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it through the `Edit Column wizard` of the grid view, Go to edit column windows and select the columns that you want to make read only and in the right pane just set the `ReadOnly` property to true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio did not allow me to set single column ReadOnly property false when Enable Editing property of DataGridView is unchecked(???). But HOKBONG's comment helped. Thanks guys.