# How to make editable only a specific column in DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a `DataGridView` to get some records from a `database` (programmatically). Also, I made the `grid` read-only so user cannot modify/edit something. At the same time, I added another column (`checkbox`) and due the property of the `grid`, I cannot select any row I want. Is there any possibility to make only one column editable? Thanks.

Code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {


                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }

            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dch = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            dch.HeaderText = "Selecteaza";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dch);
```

Edit - I use this select and I want only the column I added (`"Selecteaza"`) to be editable:

```
    "SELECT p.cod AS Numar, p.data AS Data, c.nume AS Furnizor, d.nume AS DocFurnizor, p.doc_cod AS NrDocFurnizor, p.validat AS Validat, p.facturat AS Contat, g.nume AS Gestiune 
FROM primar p INNER JOIN cf c ON p.part1=c.cf_id 
INNER JOIN gestiuni g ON p.part2 = g.gest_id 
INNER JOIN documente d ON p.doc_id = d.doc_id WHERE (p.tip = '2')
ORDER BY p.Data";
```

Comment: Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597268/how-do-i-allow-edit-only-a-particular-column-in-datagridview-in-windows-applicat

Answer (score 0):

Set `ReadOnly` to `false` for `DataGridView` and then individually set `ReadOnly` property for columns as you need.

Comment: I use this select. How can I set `ReadOnly` individually? Thanks.

`"SELECT p.cod AS Numar, p.data AS Data, c.nume AS Furnizor, d.nume AS DocFurnizor, p.doc_cod AS NrDocFurnizor, p.validat AS Validat, p.facturat AS Contat, g.nume AS Gestiune FROM primar p INNER JOIN cf c ON p.part1=c.cf_id INNER JOIN gestiuni g ON p.part2 = g.gest_id INNER JOIN documente d ON p.doc_id = d.doc_id WHERE (p.tip = '2') ORDER BY Data";`

Comment: Either update the original question or post a new question with the updated details. Also, you really need to have that detail in the question to start off with