# How do you allow the user to update datagridview using LINQ to Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've tried to change the editMode but that's not doing it. I need to allow the user to edit a column and the change will be saved back into the database. Currently the datagridview is read only. My columns are "SID" and "Mark".

This is how I bound my combobox to the datagridview

```js
private void cboeCID_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboeCID.Text);

            using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
            {
                var course = from c in db.Student_Course where c.CID == CID select new {
                SID = c.SID,
                Mark = c.Mark};
                editDataGridView.DataSource = course.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the columns you wanna be edited, and handlers like [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

In the handler just catch the changes and save it to de DB, refresh the Grid `DataSource` and it should work.

Comment: How would I set the columns to be editable, I set the datagridview's property as readonly = false, but I still can't select or enter anything.

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597268/how-do-i-allow-edit-only-a-particular-column-in-datagridview-in-windows-applicat